# How a JAR can load the hibernate.cfg.xml external file?

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't figure out how to pass the hibernate configuration file to JAR program.
I get the following error when running the JAR:

> org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not
> locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]

I tried to put the file at the same directory of the JAR, or inside the sub folder resources as it is on the project.

Update:
Here is how I'm trying to use:

```
StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
      .configure() 
      .build();  //exception throw here

sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml` file is placed inside resource folder. Works correctly when loaded from the unit test.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/)? It basically suggests using the [`Configuration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) class. Link specifically talks about using `configure(String)` for a different location within the JAR but there are overloads that take a `File` or `URL`.

Comment: That link might be outdated. You can also look at [section 3.1.4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-SessionFactory) of the user guide (_Bootstrapping -> Native Bootstrapping -> Building the SessionFactory_). The principle is the same but you'd use [`StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/registry/StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.html) instead of `Configuration`.

Comment: I changed hibernate initialization to use a File object passed to the config method of StandardServiceRegistryBuilder, instead of passing the string with the file name. This way i can load the file from any path, since File object doesn't use any loader. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that StandardServiceRegistry was trying to load hibernate.cfg.xml from the resources and the resources were not embedded in JAR.

I move the configuration file to the sub-folder 'config' and loaded it using File class, like this:

```
File config = new File("./config/hibernate.cfg.xml");   
StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .configure(config) 
    .build();
try 
{
    sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
        .buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
    throw e;
}
```